# getBaseContext() error with fragments

Tags: android, sqlite

Im creating basically a ToDo list. Im working on the database part so the user can type in items and the list will populate when they click the add button. Now I keep getting errors when I use the getBaseContext()

im following this guy's tutorials, while mine is using fragments I keep getting an error and I think its because im using fragments

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilpUe0Lkt8o

Im getting an error with the getBaseContext()

Here is my FragmentTasks.Java

```
package com.example.navbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentTasks extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener{

    public FragmentTasks() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    EditText task;
    DataHandler handler;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, container, false);
        Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        task = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, container, false);
        /* button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();

                if (activity != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });


        */

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.tasks, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String getTasks = task.getText().toString();
        handler = new DataHandler(getBaseContext()); **//Error is here!**
        handler.open();
        long id = handler.insertData(getTasks);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); **//And Here!**
        handler.close();


    }

}
```

Right at the bottom of the onClick is where the error is. Right above ^^^^^^

and here is my DataHandler.java

```
package com.example.navbar;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DataHandler {
    public static final String TASKS = "tasks";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_table";
    public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table mytable(tasks text not null);";

    DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
    Context ctx;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataHandler(Context ctx){
        this.ctx =ctx;
        dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(ctx);

    }

    private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx){
            super(ctx,DATA_BASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newVersion){

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }

    public DataHandler open(){

        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        dbhelper.close();

    }

    public long insertData(String tasks){

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(TASKS, tasks);
        return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null , content);

    }


    public Cursor returnData(){

        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {TASKS}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using getActivity() rather than getBaseContext().  The activity hosting the fragment serves as the context for the fragment.

Here is the official android developers guide which explains how to get a context in a fragment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

and here is the relevant paragraph

Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getActivity() will return null.

Based on the the above document, I think the ultimate problem is that you are implementing the onClickListener as a method of the fragment, so I am not sure the activity has even been created at that point.  You can try using getApplicationContext() or perhap even better would be to move the onclicklistener into your onCreateView method.

ie replace

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

with

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using v.getContext()

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```